# Using Grunt with Assemble without Handlebars (using Consolidatejs/Swig)?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble, swig-template

I'm trying to use [Consolidate.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js/) (with [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) rendering engine) in my `Grunfile.js` with [Assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble), as explained in [`options.engine`](http://assemble.io/docs/options-engine.html). It doesn't work:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    'use strict';

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({

        assemble: {
            options: {
                engine: 'consolidate',
                initializeEngine: function (engine, options)  { 
                    engine.engine.swig.init(options);
                }
            },
            docs: {
                files: {
                    'docs/': ['src/templates/**/*.swig' ]
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('assemble');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['assemble']);
};
```

It gives me a warning:

> Warning: Object function [..] has no method 'init'. Use --force to continue.

If I remove the `initializeEngine` option I get:

> Warning: consolidate does not support render. Use --force to continue.

How can I use Swig with Assemble? I'd like to replace the default engine Handlebars because I already know Twig engine (and it's very similar to Swig).

Answer (score 1):

Swig does not have an `init` method. You may be looking at old [documentation](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/).

Have you looked at using [Assemble-Swig](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-swig)

Comment: Assemble-swig project is not official. The options.engine is supposed to work as per documentation (my example is copy-and-past from Assemble website)... am I wrong?

Comment: assemble-swig is an official Assemble project. create an issue on that repo if you have problems, the assemble team will help you out.